# How to explain reversing an array in JavaScript using for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I need help with understanding how this code works.
task:
Without using functions, you must reverse all items in a list. That is, redo it back and forth.

Example:
Input: [-89,71,11,0,4,6]
Output:  [6,4,0,11,71,-89]

I found this example, but I need to explain how it works and be able to explain all aspects of the code:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let n = arr.length-1;

for(let i=0; i<=n/2; i++) {
  let temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[n-i];
  arr[n-i] = temp;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: step through the code in a debugger and examine the results as you go.

Comment: yes, it's better if you try to do the work yourself and come back with actual specific questions of a process you considered and didn't quite understand

Answer (score 1):

You can use much simpler like:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const reversedArr = []

for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  reversedArr.push(arr[i])
}

console.log(reversedArr)
```

Explanation is just, iterating over each item in the original array, but starting from the last item (arr.length = 5 here) and push each of them to a new array.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to reverse the array in place

Answer (score 0):

The code is just doing a reverse function.

The  `let temp = arr[i];arr[i] = arr[n-i];arr[n-i] = temp;` is trying to switch the sequence between the `i` item and the `i` item from the last element,.

In your code, n is the last element.

Example, i =0, `temp` will equal to be the first element in `arr` which is 1, and `arr[n-i]` will be the last i element (the last element) which is 7.

Then, the code set `arr[i]` (first element in `arr`) to the last element value `arr[n-i]` which is 7.

Finally, the code assign the value of the `arr[n-1]` (last element in `arr`) to `temp` which is 1 and the first element in `arr` .

So you successfully reverse the first and last element and the loop keep doing the same thing when i=1,2......

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let n = arr.length-1;

for(let i=0; i<=n/2; i++) {
  let temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[n-i];
  arr[n-i] = temp;
}
console.log(arr);
```